# Signage app written in Angular 9 runs without user interaction like daemon with MSAL and Azure

Tags: angular, azure, daemon, azure-ad-msal

I created a signage Angular 9 app using MSAL and Azure-based on MSAL angular samples found in GitHub. Because of the signage app, it must run 24 hours 7 days 365 days without user interaction. It ran for a dozen hours then eventually stopped with an error "AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in.". I'd like to make the angular app like a daemon shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview which even doesn't need any user logins. With Angular, is it possible to create a daemon app or an app without further sign-in?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.timer2 = setInterval(() => {
        this.getSignageFromAPI();    //get a list from API hosted in Azure and display in a page in Angular.
    }, 180000); //three minutes.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Deamon applications are generally to support server scenario. Where angular wont support for your requirement. 
If you still want to achieve your requirement you need to run ng build -prod, and then take the dist (or whatever your output folder is) and serve it under any server program you like (Apache, nginx, IIS, etc.).
At the end of the day, this is a folder of just static files, so, it doesn't have any special server requirements. Regarding the Token expiration
or else you can choose any of the following [.net/.Net Core/Java/Asp .Net Webapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview).
Node.js application can run as its own process. You can use nodejs combination with angular to achieving the Deamon app.

Comment: You are right. My angular app is not a server-side app and its details could be exposed such as key, client secret, etc. I achieved my goal with Angular. My API and Angular sites are available only internally or inside my organization network. The Angular signage runs perfectly since May.